# Issues accessing Object setup in test data

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am working on a University question. I have setup 2 Models, one for Pupils and one for Activities.
Pupils looks like this:

```
public class Pupil
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Pupil(string surname, string forename, string title)
    {
        Surname = surname;
        Forename = forename;
        Title = title;
    }

    public Pupil() { }
}
```

Activities looks like this:

```
public class Activity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }    
    public List<Pupil> Members  { get; set; }

    public Activity() { }

    public Activity(string name, string location, List<Pupil> members)
    {
        Name = name;
        Location = location;
        Members = members;
    }
}
```

I have been asked to setup Test Data in the Test project for this, which I have done:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private Pupil pupil1 = new Pupil("Smith", "Jim", "Mr");
    private Pupil pupil2 = new Pupil("Jones", "Karl", "Mr");
    private Pupil pupil3 = new Pupil("Bradshaw", "Lara", "Mrs");
    private Pupil pupil4 = new Pupil("Thompson", "Jane", "Miss");
    private Pupil pupil5 = new Pupil("Johnson", "Dave", "Mr");




    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Activity activity1 = new Activity("Purchasing", "Top floor", new List<Pupil> { pupil1, pupil2 });

    }
}
```

Now, I have to create a function in a suitable area, which takes the Activity name as an input parameter and returns a list of surnames who's in this department

I created this function within the main Program.cs file:

```
public IList<string> funcSurnamesInActivity(string activityName)
{
    IList<string> surnames = new List<string>();
    Activity act = new Activity();
    List<Pupil> persons = act.Members.ToList();
    foreach (Pupil person in persons)
    {
        surnames.Add(person.Surname);
    }

    return surnames;
    
}
```

But I do not know how to use the string activityName to find the Activity from my test data to then continue with the code I have written to get the list of Pupils.

I can do this by passing the Activity in as a parameter but this is not the question.

Any help is appreciated

I have tried to access this but don't know how. The only way I see possible is to send Activity as a parameter option rather than just the Activity name string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your test data are inside the test class (pupil instances: pupil1, pupil2 etc).
2. You don't have test data for activity, except for the one instance in TestMethod1. Also, since you say you must use the activity name as a parameter, that means, the function should have access to a list of activities.
3. If you create the function in a separate class (Program.cs), you won't have access to the test data within the test class. In other words, you can't access the pupil & activity objects because they are not "in scope".

So, to address point #2, create some test data for activity in the test class. To address point #3 write you search function in the test class itself. In that way, the function has access to the test data.

Then you can call that method from your TestMethod1 (currently your TestMethod1 doesn't test anything).

So, preserving most of your code, if I would modify only your test class, it would look like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private Pupil pupil1 = new Pupil("Smith", "Jim", "Mr");
    private Pupil pupil2 = new Pupil("Jones", "Karl", "Mr");
    private Pupil pupil3 = new Pupil("Bradshaw", "Lara", "Mrs");
    private Pupil pupil4 = new Pupil("Thompson", "Jane", "Miss");
    private Pupil pupil5 = new Pupil("Johnson", "Dave", "Mr");

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of activities for testing
    /// </summary>
    private IList<Activity> GetActivityList()
    {
        List<Activity> activitiesToReturn = new List<Activity>();

        // Add activities to the list
        activitiesToReturn.Add(new Activity("Purchasing", "Top floor", new List<Pupil> { pupil1, pupil2 }));
        activitiesToReturn.Add(new Activity("Selling", "5th floor", new List<Pupil> { pupil2, pupil3 }));
        activitiesToReturn.Add(new Activity("Borrowing", "4th floor", new List<Pupil> { pupil3, pupil4 }));
        activitiesToReturn.Add(new Activity("Lending", "3rd floor", new List<Pupil> { pupil4, pupil5 }));
        activitiesToReturn.Add(new Activity("Returning", "Ground floor", new List<Pupil> { pupil5, pupil1 }));

        return activitiesToReturn;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // Use your function to search the list of activities
        // for the given activity name
        IList<string> surnamesInPurchasing = FuncSurnamesInActivity("Purchasing");

        // "Purchasing" activity must return 2 surnames
        Assert.AreEqual(2, surnamesInPurchasing.Count);
        // One of the surnames in the list must be "Smith", our 1st pupil
        Assert.IsTrue(surnamesInPurchasing.Contains("Smith"));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of activities for testing
    /// </summary>
    public IList<string> FuncSurnamesInActivity(string activityName)
    {
        IList<string> surnames = new List<string>();
        // Get list of activities
        IList<Activity> activities = GetActivityList();

        // Fetch the 1st element in the activities list
        // that matches the given activity name
        Activity activityFound = activities.First(a => a.Name == activityName);

        if (activityFound == null)
        {
            // If we didn't find the activity,
            // returns empty list of surnames
            return surnames;
        }

        List<Pupil> persons = activityFound.Members.ToList();
        foreach (Pupil person in persons)
        {
            surnames.Add(person.Surname);
        }

        return surnames;
    }
}
```

What I have changed:

- Added a method to get a list of activities (test data). Your pupils instances are used here
- Modified your function to search the activity name in the above-mentioned list of activities. Note that I fetch the 1st element that matches the name (in case you add duplicates)
- Modified the test method to use your function to run actual tests

Now you can customize this to your needs. Hope this helps